# python process huge ascii data in TCP

Tags: python-3.x

I have to listen to a server, which pushes a lot of data to the client (about 10000 packets per second, each packet is about 1500bytes). I have to accept and process this data. All data is ASCII. I found the Python script below cannot process it fast enough, and this results in data congestion:

```
event_loop.create_connection(protocol, host, prot)
```

How can I improve this program?

Comment: POST it from the server all at once with curl.

Comment: Improved grammar.

Comment: it also is a tcp connection. i has used pypy or when recive just do print(),I think it is not a Python performance issue